# Different behaviors from SQL Server than from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, openrowset

I am currently developing a C# web application that executes a SQL Server stored procedure. The stored procedure is an `OpenRowSet` query, that pulls data from an excel file and then inputs the data into a SQL Server table.

If I execute the stored procedure in an SSMS query window everything works fine:

> (160 rows affected) Completion time: 2021-09-07T15:54:14.1558312-04:00

If I execute the stored procedure from Visual Studio, I get the following message:

> OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Table$'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'Table$' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.

I had assumed this was a permissions issue, but after running a profile on the call, Both the SSMS execution and the VS call are executed by the same user.

Here is the C# code:

```
public class DataPut
{
        public static string _connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["_connection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connection);

        public void putReports(string sheetname, string filename, string tablename)
        {
            string query = "sp_DataImport";            
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tablename", tablename);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SheetName", sheetname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FilePath", filename);

            conn.Open();

            //cmd.CommandTimeout = 120;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
}
```

Here is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_DataImport]
    @SheetName varchar(20),
    @FilePath varchar(200),
    @TableName varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(1000)
     
    IF OBJECT_ID (@TableName,'U') IS NOT NULL
      SET @SQL = 'insert INTO [' + @TableName +'] SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
                         ''Excel 12.0;Database=' + @FilePath + ''',
                          ''SELECT * FROM [' + @SheetName + '] Where [Column] = ''''Value'''' AND [Column] =''''Value'''' AND  [Column] = ''''Value'''''')'
    ELSE
      SET @SQL = 'SELECT * INTO [' + @TableName +'] FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
                         ''Excel 12.0;Database=' + @FilePath + ''',
                           ''SELECT * FROM [' + @SheetName + '] Where [Column] = ''''Value'''' AND [Column] =''''Value'''' AND  [Column] = ''''Value'''''')'

    PRINT @SQL
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
END
```

Any idea why these would have different behaviors?

Comment: 1. Your procedure is why open to injection attacks, if you are injecting, you need to do so **safely**. 2. `sp_` is a prefix reserved by Microsoft; it should *not*  be used for using objects. Doing so comes at a performance penalty, and can mean your procedure simply stops working one day.

Comment: It may be your bitness. Try running it on x86.

Comment: Are they definitely connected to the same SQLS? Same connection string?

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. 
-Larnu - I will update both, but I'll have to readup on the Injection part.
-GH DEVOps, if this runs as 32Bit it opens a whole host of OLEDB issues and every one of them seems to have a solution of running it in 64Bit, as this is what the SQL server is running. 
-Caius JArd,  Yes they are on the same database - confirmed by the profiler. 
-SMor - Visual Studio claims .Add is depricated and they suggest the addwithvalue, but I will give it a shot.

Comment: And where physically is this file located relative to both the server instance and the application (yours or SSMS) used to execute this procedure. In short, what is the path you pass for ingestion?

Comment: @Smor - both are on my laptop, as is the excel file.

Comment: Since you are already using profiler, you could give procmon a go. It will tell you what file it's trying to open, who it's trying to open it as etc. It should make it obvious what the difference is. You just need to wade through all the noise. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: BTW calling a proc that uses openrowset to import an excel file is not a good idea. There's a lot of things that can go wrong (as you are discovering). Since you already have a C# solution, depending on your requirements it might be better to open the file from C# and insert it. Because for example, the file currently needs to exist in a location accessible from SQL Server. If you were to deploy this to end users they would need to work out how they are going to get the file to the correct location. If you were to deploy this to an enterprise, it probably wouldn't be allowed.

Comment: "Visual Studio claims .Add is depricated and they suggest the addwithvalue, but I will give it a shot." - what version of VS says that method is deprecated? I just checked with 2019 and 2015 (both of which I use all the time) and neither of them claim this method is deprecated.